# How to set managed metadata as global navigation in communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, community-site, communication-site

How to set global navigation using managed metadata in communication site SharePoint online and update left navigation using navigation tab.
I am also not able to activate publishing feature in communication site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication site doesn't support global navigation using managed metadata. see below link.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Communications-Sites-AMA/Do-Communications-Sites-support-Global-Navigation/td-p/83158

you need to create either team site.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate feature using ShellScript as shown below

Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell
$siteurl="https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteurl)

$username="username"
$secure_string_pwd = convertto-securestring "pwd" -asplaintext -force

$clientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $secure_string_pwd)

$site = $clientContext.Site;
$featureguid = new-object System.Guid "f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa"
$site.Features.Add($featureguid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None);
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery();